# Vue Transition Collapsing Snap

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2

I'm curious how others have solved this problem. When I transition elements whose layout affects the page, there's a snap--or layout adjustment--when the transitioned element is removed. This makes sense, but I'm not sure how best to approach it. Here's an example:
https://codepen.io/noynek/pen/yXeRBY

HTML

```
<div id="demo">
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="show" style="float:left">
      <input placeholder="field 1" />
      <input placeholder="field 2" />
    </div>
  </transition>
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
  show: true
 }
})
```

CSS

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active in <2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}
```

Comment: The button must be positioned at the same place?

Comment: please describe the desired behavior

Comment: The goal is for the button to animate to it's new position rather than snap. It's a common problem when collapsing and expanding things that affect layout. Animating a negative left margin or position would work, but it's gonna have performance problems.

Comment: I've updated the example to show the desired animation by animating margins. This won't get 60fps of course, but it shows the desired effect.